# 'React/RCTComponentEvent.h' file not found

Tags: react-native, version, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I faced this issue after upgrading my react-native-fbsdk to 1.0.1

```
/Users/mahgolfathi/plusless-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/ios/RCTFBSDK/login/RCTFBSDKLoginButtonManager.m:22:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTComponentEvent.h' file not found
#import <React/RCTComponentEvent.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- you should upgrade your react-native version to 6

- check your version using `react-native -v`

2- change the line with the import in `RCTFBSDKLoginButtonManager.m`:

`#import<React/RCTComponentEvent.h>`

changed to:

`#import "RCTComponentEvent.h"`

3- select project RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj, select target RCTFBSDK, select Build Settings, search for 'header', select 'Header Search Paths' and add this new line: `${SRCROOT}/../../../node_modules/react-native/React/Base`, as non-recursive.

Comment: what do you mean by : « you should upgrade your react-native version to 6 » ? v0.60.* ?

Comment: @Gura well , yes